# Silverlight : Best design practice for localization

Tags: design-patterns, silverlight-4.0

HI,

What is the best practice for localization of application in silverlight. I have a requirement where same application will be used for multipl customers and with multiple language support. In this case if I provide different resource files for different customer terminologies and also seperate resouce file for all common terms, is it fine to do? I suppose the clinet should be getting only that satellite assembly which is specific to him.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are not many things you can do right now. The localization plainly sucks and there's no best practice at all. The current mechanism uses .resx files, which get unmaintainable in a medium-large applications but what's worst is that you'll lose design time view, because no value will be displayed in design mode.

Hopefully things will get better by the release of Silverlight 5.0 and you probably can use some elegant solutions that are available in WPF that use MarkupExtension (which is not there in Silverlight 4.0).